# Is there a jquery plugin to cut long column titles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a dynamically constructed table on a page. It contains a collection of columns. Their number from 4 to 10. Then there are 4 columns it is all ok. But then there 10 columns - some titles in a header do not fit column width.

I want to know if some plugin exists that can cut off the titles(and set '...' in the end) or replace them by abbreviation if there not enough space to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware you are asking for a jQuery plugin, but I think it should be mentioned that this can also be done with `CSS`

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

See for example [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis)

Comment: It seemed to be more complicated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Its not cross browser, See [dot dot dot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin

Comment: I checked the link, ff shim is there. Ignore but comment. Just keeping it to let others know about this plugin

Comment: according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/text-overflow) most current browsers support this but it might need a prefix. (even IE6 is claimed to support it)

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

```
$('table td').expander({
    slicePoint:       80, 
    expandPrefix:     '... ', 
    expandText:       '[...]',
    collapseTimer:    5000, 
    userCollapseText: '[^]'
  });
```

Config slicePoint to a number fit your td.